# How to find the follow of the following grammar

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, language-agnostic, ll-grammar

## Grammar

```
S->(A)
A->CB
B->;A|ε
C->x|S
```

I have find the *First* of the grammar:

```
First(S)={(}
First(B)={;,ε}
First(C)={x,(}
First(A)=First(C)={x,(}
```

I have trouble finding the *Follow* of the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

The Follow sets are

`Follow(S)={$,),;}`

`Follow(B)={)}`

`Follow(C)={:,)}`

`Follow(A)={)}`